# Can we forge the result of `os.sysconf('SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN')`?

Tags: python, linux

In a program I cannot really change (for instance, `meld` installed in `/usr`), I'm looking for a way to restrict the number of processes it'll spawn.

Internally, I see it executes

```
multiprocessing.Pool(None, .....)
```

which in turn asks `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` that returns `os.sysconf('SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN')`.

I'm on a Linux (centos) node that I share with many people. Spawning 48 processes is not acceptable in my context. The problem happens with the version of meld installed on the system, of course I could use the latest version. Yet it won't solve the general problem that there are other (Python) offenders that naively monopolize every available CPU.

Is there any simple way to inject into `os.sysconf('SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN')` what we'd like to see returned, 4 for instance?